# Electrum load_wallet through json-rpcs does not accept "wallet" parameter

Tags: json-rpc, electrum, electrum-console

When calling `load_wallet` through json-rpc, using "wallet" param with a path to the wallet throws an error:

```
Commands.load_wallet() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wallet'
```

In the same time, `electrum help load_wallet` lists `wallet` as an acceptable option:

[image: electrum help load_wallet]

The question is, how do I specify wallet path when calling load_wallet through json-rpc.

Example payload:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"test","method":"load_wallet","params":{"wallet": "/electrum/testnet/wallets/orders001"}}
```

Comment: are you running electrumX ?

Comment: No, my question is about Electrum daemon and json-rpc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the "wallet" parameter is not recognized by the "load_wallet" method in the context of the JSON-RPC call you are making.

One solution could be to pass the wallet path as a command-line argument when starting the JSON-RPC server. For example, if you are using Electrum, you could start the server with the following command:

```
electrum --testnet --rpcuser=<username> --rpcpassword=<password> --rpchost=localhost --rpcport=8000 /electrum/testnet/wallets/orders001
```

This command starts the Electrum server in testnet mode and specifies the wallet path as the last argument.

Once the server is running, you can make JSON-RPC requests to it without including the "wallet" parameter in the payload. The server should automatically load the wallet specified in the command-line argument.

Alternatively, you could try using the "load_wallet_file" method instead of "load_wallet". According to the Electrum documentation, "load_wallet_file" takes a single argument, which is the path to the wallet file. Here is an example payload:

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"test","method":"load_wallet_file","params":["/electrum/testnet/wallets/orders001"]}`

Note that the wallet path is passed as an array element in the "params" field, not as a separate "wallet" parameter.

Comment: None of the solutions proposed help when working with multiple wallets via json-rpc. I need to specify the target wallet for each wallet-related command, and keep multiple wallets loader.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `select_wallet` method of the Electrum JSON-RPC API to switch between wallets

for example for a wallet `dat_test_wallet_01`

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "test", "method": "select_wallet", "params": {"name": "dat_test_wallet_01"}}
```

for multiple wallet you can use `load_wallet` like

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "test", "method": "load_wallet", "params": {"path": "/electrum/testnet/wallets/dat_test_wallet_01"}}
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "test", "method": "select_wallet", "params": {"name": "dat_test_wallet_01"}}
```

Comment: I cannot rely on "select_wallet" functionality, because there might be another "select_wallet" between my two commands, and the selected wallet gets changed in between.